# Magento 1.9.2.3 : Google Chrome Security Update make payment redirect page error

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.2.3, after successful payment page redirect to https://domain.in/checkout/cart/  Screenshot: https://snipboard.io/G5L4ej.jpg

Error :

After successful payment return Shopping Cart is Empty message instead of the success page.

**Note: Is it recommended to set Google cookie SameSite to temporarily solve this issue?**

How to solve this issue? Get & Post method error.